# What really happens when I use varchar(10) in the sqlite command-line shell?

Tags: sql, sqlite, types

I'm messing around with SQLite for the first time by working through some of the SQLite documentation. In particular, I'm using [Command Line Shell For SQLite](http://sqlite.org/sqlite.html) and the SoupToNuts [SQLite Tutorial](http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/readme_sqlite_tutorial.html) on Sourceforge.

According to the SQLite [datatype documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), there are only 5 datatypes in SQLite. However, in the two tutorial documents above, I see where the authors use commands such as

```
create table tbl1(one varchar(10), two smallint);
create table t1 (t1key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,data TEXT,num double,timeEnter DATE);
```

which contain datatypes that aren't listed by SQLite, yet these commands work just fine.

Additionally, when I ran .dump to see the SQL statements, these datatype specifications are preserved:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE Vulnerabilities (
   ...> VulnerabilityID unsigned smallint primary key,
   ...> VulnerabilityName varchar(10),
   ...> VulnerabilityDescription longtext);
sqlite> .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE Vulnerabilities (
VulnerabilityID unsigned smallint primary key,
VulnerabilityName varchar(10),
VulnerabilityDescription longtext);
COMMIT;
sqlite>
```

So, what gives? Does SQLite keep a reference for any datatype specified in the SQL yet converts it behind the scenes to one of its 5 datatypes? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQLite uses dynamic typing](http://www2.sqlite.org/faq.html#q2).
SQLite will allow you to insert an integer into that VARCHAR(10) column.
SQLite will not complain if insert a string longer than 10 characters into that column.

As el.pescado mentions, SQLite has storage classes AKA "affinities".
If you attempt to insert a column belongs to [a particular affinity](http://www2.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity), then SQLite will try to convert that value to match the affinity.
If the conversion doesn't work, the value is inserted as-is.

So while your more granular datatypes are saved (apparently) to the metadata table, they are not being used by SQLite.

Comment: Would it be a "Good Thing" to still use the more granular datatypes?

Comment: Unless you're simultaneously using your data-definition statements (DDL) with other RDBMSs, I don't see any reason to do so.

Comment: I was thinking in case I wanted to port it to something like MySQL or SQL Express down the road.

Comment: In that case it makes sense to use the more-specific types so you don't have so much to rewrite in your DDL statements.

Answer (score 0):

There are not five datatypes, rather 5 datatype "classes" that "real" datatypes fall into. So that, TINYINT, SMALLINT and BIGINT are three different datatypes, but all belonging to the INTEGER storage class.